# update and save data to a .txt file daily

Tags: python, for-loop, menu, while-loop, text-files

I'm trying to create something similar to a journal of my daily fluid intake, food, exercise, etc. I have created a few menus do ask user for specific input that is pre-defined in the menus. From there I need to collect all the output print data and save to a file, the file will be updated daily (asking the user for the same pre-defined input.

Code is pretty long, but looks like this:

```
health = open('healthy.txt','a+')

date = input('Date:   ')

#Loop Menu for Exercise info for that day.
loop=True
while (loop):
    print ()
    print ("----------------------------------")
    print ("1 = Yoga")
    print ("2 = Cardio")
    print ("3 = Walk")
    print ("4 = Dance")
    print ("5 = Rest/None")
    print ("D = Done")
    print ("----------------------------------")
    print ()  

    exer = input('Exercise:   ')

    if (exer =='1'):
        print("Yoga")
    elif (exer =='2'):
        print("Cardio")
    elif (exer =='3'):
        print ("Walk")
    elif (exer =='4'):
        print ("Dance")
    elif (exer == '5'):
        print ("Rest/None")
    elif (exer =='d' or exer =='D'):
        loop=False
    else:
        print ("Invalid Option")
#End Exercise Menu        


dur = input('Duration(in minutes):   ')

#Loop menu for the Food Intake for particular date. 
loop=True
while (loop):
    print ()
    print ("----------------------------------")
    print ("1 = Protein")
    print ("2 = Starch")
    print ("3 = Fruit")
    print ("4 = Vegetable")
    print ("D = Done")
    print ("----------------------------------")
    print ()  

    food = input('Food:  ')

    if (food =='1'):
        print("Protein")
    elif (food =='2'):
        print("Starch")
    elif (food =='3'):
        print ("Fruit")
    elif (food =='4'):
        print ("Vegetable")
    elif (food =='d' or food =='D'):
        loop=False
    else:
        print ("Invalid Option")


#End Food Menu

fluid = input('Fluid Intake Total:   ')
#for line in health:

#Final print of info to be written to file
#not sure if I need the next four lines
food_true = False
food_total = 0
exer_true = False
exer_total = 0

for char in exer:
    if (exer_true == "Yoga"):
       print ("Yoga", end=" ")
    if (exer_true == "Cardio"):
        print ("Cardio", end=" ")
    if (exer_true == "Walk"):
        print ("Walk", end= " ")
    if (exer_true == "Dance"):
        print ("Dance",end=" ")
    if (exer_true == "Rest/None"):
        print ("Rest/None",end=" ")        
    else:
        loop=False

while(loop):
    if (food_true == "Protein"): 
        print ("Protein", end=" ")
    if (food_true == "Starch"):
        print ("Starch", end=" ")
    if (food_true == "Fruit"):
        print ("Fruit", end= " ")
    if (food_true == "Vegetable"):
        print ("Vegetable",end=" ")
    else:
        loop=False

print ("{:>10}".format("Date:        "),date)
print ("{:>10}".format("Exercises:   "),exer_total)
print ("{:>10}".format("Duration:    "),dur)
print ("{:>10}".format("Foods:       "),food_total)
print ("{:>10}".format("Fluids:      "),fluid)
print("-"*60)

#Save/Write to file function will be here
#Save/Write to file function will be here
health.write(info)#word "info" is a place holder only for final code info
health.close()
```

I want to be able to print out the info only (this does not include saving the info to the file)for the following in a neat looking file(format doesn't really matter as long as it is neat): Date: output; Exercise: output(all if applicable) ;Duration:output ;Food:output(all four if applicable);Fluids: output

Each day I will run the program and update my daily info for all the above.
Then the file needs to have the info written and saved to the same file each day(cannot be a new file each day, hence the use of the the following at start of the code, this is a MUST):
    health = open('healthy.txt','a+')

Comment: just trolling, what's "Protien" ?

Comment: typo, my bad.... protein love :)